# Push into referenced associative, multidimensional array returned by class method

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, pass-by-reference, php-8

As part of my ongoing efforts to simplify the legacy codebase for a CodeIgniter3 application, I'm currently running into a problem. In short, I've dealt with an error statement earlier stating:

```
can't use method return value in write context
```

which might ring a bell for some readers. Nonetheless, I haven't seen this error since but I suspect that something is still going wrong. In short, I'm trying to push an associative array into another associative, multidimensional array which is the result of a method that returns a reference.

I've set up a system to easily alter the contents of a JSON, which is returned by reference through this method:

```
/**
 * Function :   items
 * Target   :   Retrieves a reference to the items, decoded
 * 
 * @author  :   Angev
 * @since   :   2.0
 * @version :   1.0
 * 
 * @return      Referenced link to index 'items'.
 */
public function & items()
{
    $list = (is_array($this->data)) ? $this->data : json_decode($this->data, true);
    return $list['items'];

}
```

In short, the method `$this->items()` is part of a Model named 'CheckList'. The Checklist corresponds with a data-table in my database, which includes a 'data' column that represents the data belonging to a certain checklist: the JSON I'm trying to alter and which you can see being returned in this method. Another way of seeing the output of `$this->items()` is that it should return a reference to `$this->data['items']`.

This goes all and well, I've used this method many times during development - as a shorthand to accessing `['list']` - and it always returns exactly what I need it to return: a multidimensional array filled with unique indexes (strings) that contain the data belonging to each item of the checklist.

The problem however, arises in a method named `update_checklist()` in particular the following section:

```
  $this->items()[$uid] = [
                           'parent_id' => $parent['id'],
                           ... ,
                         ];
```

I'd expect the method to add an index to the array returned by $this->items(), but it doesn't.
I'm not quite sure what goes wrong in this context, since I have earlier seen the error message written at the top of this question, but haven't seen it since.

However, no index is added to the array and whenever I do an immediate var_dump($this->items()) afterwards. It just shows the state of the array as it was before the execution of `update_checklist()`.

In search of an answer, I've also tried wrapping the callback in parentheses, but to no avail:

```
  ( $this->items() )[$uid] = . . .
```

To temporary fix the problem, I've resorted to a more direct alteration of the ['items'] array by doing the following:

```
$this->data = json_decode($this->data, true);      
$this->data['items'][$uid] = [
                               'parent_id' => $parent['id'],
                               ... ,
                             ];
```

Nonetheless, even though the code above works, I'm left wondering what the flaw is in my logic concerning the method reference return of `$this->items()` and why I cannot use this method when pushing into the referenced array.

How can I write the required changes to make `$this->items()[]` function as intended? Or I'd be interested in more clarity into the theory behind this structure and why it can't work.

Answer (score 1):

As always, once you start formulating a question, you stumble upon the flaws in your logic. I've read over this question with a colleague and while discussing the solution just magically presented itself. I'll include the answer for future reference to anyone having the same problem.

```
/**
 * Function :   items
 * Target   :   Retrieves a reference to the items, decoded
 * 
 * @author  :   Angev
 * @since   :   2.0
 * @version :   1.0
 * 
 * @return      Referenced link to index 'items'.
 */
public function & items()
{
    $list = (is_array($this->data)) ? $this->data : json_decode($this->data, true);
    return $list['items'];

}
```

The problem lies withing the `items()` method. This method surely returns a reference, but the reference is made to the preliminary variable `$list`, which in turn has no direct reference to `$this->data`. So instead of refering to `$this->data['items']`, the method returns a reference to `$list`, which is essentially a copy of `$this->data`, no no real reference.

To fix the problem, the following code was used:

```
public function & items()
{
    if(!is_array($this->data) ) $this->data = json_decode($this->data, true);
    return $this->data['items'];

}
```

As expected, the method now returns a reference to the actual data object.

So in short, what I've learned is that if you let a method return a reference, you need to make sure that whatever the method returns is **actually a reference** instead of a copy of the data you're trying to reference to.

I'll leave this question open for now to allow others to share any knowledge of insights in this matter.